# How to select document with has_many relation with Mongoid

Tags: mongoid, has-many

I know that my problem is the trivial one, but I need some help.

I have two mongoid classes with `has_many` relation:

```
class Container
    ...
    has_many: items
    ...
end

class Item
    ...
    field :date, type => Date
    belongs_to: container
    ...
end
```

I need all containers that have item at the particular date.

Here is the scope that doesn't work as expected. It returns both, the containters that do have, and the containers that don't have items at the given date:

```
class Container
    ...
    scope :with_items_on, ->(date){ where(:_id.in => Item.on(date).only(:container_id).distinct(:container_id)) }
    ...
end
```

`.on(date)` is scope that returns correctly all Items for the given date.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Place.rb**

`has_many :reviews`

**Review.rb**

`belongs_to :place`

*Mongoid 3* does not support it

`Place.where('reviews.state' => 'published')`

Answer (score -2):

The mongoid querying system is elegantly powerful, so this query can be boiled down to a pretty simple statement. Here it is as a class method:

```
class Container
  #...snip...
  has_many :items

  def self.with_items_on(date)
    where( 'items.date' => date )
  end
end
```

Or as a scope:

```
class Container
  #...snip...
  has_many :items

  scope :with_items_on, ->(date){ where('item.date' => date) }
end
```

Comment: Not quite sure why this was downvoted - anyone care to shed some light?

Comment: perhaps this: `->(date){ where('item.date' => date) }` should be `{|date| where('item.date' => date) }`?